# Can you link a column in one table which has column names of another table with that second table

Tags: ms-access, join

I have two tables A and B

Table A has a list of all columns in table B
[image: Table A column of Table B's column names]

Table B has values in each column
[image]

In MS Access, is it possible to create a query linking the values in the column in Table A with the Columns in Table B?

The SELECT statement I am thinking of is something along the lines of:

SELECT A.Col1,A.Col2,B.Col1,B.Col2

FROM TableA AS A

LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB AS B

-- this is where I get stuck but in pseudo-code might be ..
ON value in A.Col3 = B.Col3

Thanks for any help on this even if it's "No, this can't be done in Access"

Comment: These tables do not have relationship. Requirement does not make sense. You show only 1 column for TableA yet your pseudocode references Col3. What do you expect output to look like?

Comment: OK, Thanks for the reply. Column 3 in table A holds the column names for table B so essentially I want the query to return the relevant columns of table A and the value of the column in B whose column name is in A.Col3. - Yes, the pseudo code above was written wrong.

Comment: What exactly is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question? What is "linking" trying to say? [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097) PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Please clarify via edits, not comments. Before you post look at the formatted version of your post below the edit box. Read the edit help re inline & block formats for code & quotations.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TableB is not normalized data structure. It has no relationship with TableA and join is not possible nor does it make sense. Do a UNION query on TableB to reorganize data to normalized structure.

I presume TableB has a unique identifier field.

```
SELECT ID, "SourceOfReferrals_SQ001" AS Source, SourceOfReferrals_SQ001 AS Data FROM TableB
UNION SELECT ID, "SourceOfReferrals_SQ002", SourceOfReferrals_SQ002 FROM TableB
UNION SELECT ID, "SourceOfReferrals_SQ003", SourceOfReferrals_SQ003 FROM TableB
UNION SELECT ID, "SourceOfReferrals_SQ004", SourceOfReferrals_SQ004 FROM TableB
UNION SELECT ID, "SourceOfReferrals_SQ005", SourceOfReferrals_SQ005 FROM TableB;
```

Now this query can be joined to TableA if there are other fields in TableA you want data from.

Alternative is VBA looping fields of recordset to write data to a normalized table.

Comment: Yes, it's not Normalised. I was just wondering if there was a work-around. UNION won't work for me because I'd have to write out about 700 Union statements (in fact there are four tables of columns with values but if I'd got it working for one then I'd replicate it for the other three). I think my best hope is to do this trough VBA in Excel. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Or VBA in Access could write data to a normalized table.

Comment: Any 2 tables can be meaningfully joined on any condition. Normalization is irrelevant to querying. Whatever you're trying to say, if it makes sense, you're not saying it.